# Multiply PHP Result By A Decimal

Tags: php

I am a PHP noob and this code is outputting a number.  I would like to take this number and multiply it by a decimal.  I have been searching and banging my head for hours.  Please excuse my ignorance and thank you for any help!

```
<strong><?= CarRental::t('Amount Payable Today:') ?><br>
    <?php if (isset($vehicle->prices)  && !empty($vehicle->prices)) { ?>
        <span class="additional xxlarge carrental_total_amount"> - </span>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <span class="additional xxlarge"><?= CarRental::t('Not available') ?></span>
    <?php } ?></strong><
```

Comment: Which number are you trying to multiply ? I don't see any multiplication?

Comment: Hello, this string is outputting a result.  I would like to take this result and multiply it by a decimal.  I think I have to multiply the $vehicle->prices variable but I am not sure.  This is outputting a number and I want to multiply this number and have the result printed.  Thanks again I am a noob and have this code to try to modify.

Comment: So you want to multiply `$vehicle->prices` by something?

Comment: Yes, but I keep trying to express it with * and it keeps breaking the site. I dont know how to express it properly.

Comment: When you say breaking the site, could you be a little more specific? What error messages are you receiving?

Comment: Just a blank screen.  I don't know how to format it properly, it seems.

Comment: `$vehicle->prices` is not echoed anywhere, why would you want to multiply it? `isset()` and `empty()` require a variable as argument, it's not possible, and is meaningless, to pass result of multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having issues when trying to multiply a `string` variable by a float then it could mean that you need to cast it before performing the calculation.

So something like so may help :

```
// replace 0.5 with your own decimal point number
echo (int)$vehicle->prices * (float) 0.5
```

See the following link from the manual on type juggling - [LINK](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)